# organize 3-2 pattern with nth child CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to get a pattern of three elements, two elements, three elements... with nth-child pseudo-selector. This is as far as I have got:
https://codepen.io/juanor/pen/yooeNV

```
li.hex:nth-child(3n+1){
    clear: left;
}
li.hex:nth-child(6n+4){
    clear: left;
    margin-left: 83px;
}
```

I don't know if this is a real pattern or if I should select directly all possible items I need to clear (1,4,6,9,11,14...). So far I know I have to select all 5-1th elements but not sure how to do it easily. Maybe calc? Not sure.

Thank you in advance for all your help.

Comment: Please post all code necessary to reproduce the problem in the question itself. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if i understand correctly then this will produce the desired 3,2 pattern you want

```
li.hex:nth-child(5n+4),li.hex:nth-child(5n+6){
    clear: left;
}
li.hex:nth-child(5n+4){
    clear: left;
margin-left: 83px;
}
```